# woocommerce. $product->get_type() returns simple instead of custom one

Tags: php, oop, woocommerce, methods, product

I have such a piece of code:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'custom_selector' );

function custom_selector( $types ) {
    
    $types['book'] = 'Book';
    return $types;
}



add_action( 'init', 'custom_product' );

function custom_product() {

    class WC_Product_Book extends WC_Product {
        
        public function get_type() {
            return 'book';
        }

        public function __construct( $product ) {


            $this->product_type = 'book';

            parent::__construct( $product );

        }
    }
}
```

after submitting new (book) product, if I use $product->get_type() I get: 'simple' instead of 'book'
why!!!

Comment: I have tested your code, it works as I get "book" as product type using `$product->get_type()`… Now `$this->product_type = 'book';` should be removed (`product_type` property is not defined and not needed since WooCommerce 3).  Also the constructor function should be first (before get_type)…